# Andorid Google Map not working when someone get project from GIT

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have create a project which is using Google Map Api. By me all is working good but when someone get my code from GitHub there is a problem with authentication and map isnt showing. How anyone idea what i'm doing wrong? There is the issue from android studio which download the code from githube. [image]

Comment: do you share your API key within your code or has everyone to create a new API key?

Comment: Try with server key instead of android key this will help you.

Comment: Have you added debug hash in google console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to generate **Server Key** instead of android key this will help you out and never face this problem with anyone who download your project.This will always help me out.

Comment: how can i generate server key? Should i change any properties on console developers?

Comment: In the Restrictions section of the page, select “IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)” and insert the appropriate server IP addresses - which ip i should there write?

Comment: @forfiter9 you can accept the answer if you feel the problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

The generated API Google Maps key is related to the certificate which will be used to sign your Android app

so your colleagues are using their own debug certificate to sign the app after they have checked out the code from github, that is the reason why the maps api key does not fit

So they should create their own api key and you should not check in your api key in you github repo

Answer (score 0):

You can get his Pc id and ganarate a api key for that pc, then add it to your git repository  ,, and dont forget to change the key in manifest

Comment: I'll try to fined something for you